# How to use GET and queryset in classed based views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i have two models with random farmers and animals (names / weight ) and i want to use the GET method, in my template, to apply a filter in my view on my models. For instance: show me all data with the name "xyz"

this was my approach:

**models.py**

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    <...>

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey('Farmer', related_name='farmername', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    <...>
```

so this is my template. when i submit a value it will show up in my browser adress

**template.html**

```
    <...>
<form action="" method="GET">
    name: <input type="text" name="q"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

    <...>
```

this was my approach to fit in the GET method and Q into my view
**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q

    <...>

class HomeView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'farmapi/search.html'
   http_method_names = ['get']

   def get(self, request):
        query = request.GET.get("q")

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['farmers'] = Farmer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)|Q(last_name__icontains=query))
        context['animals'] = Animal.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))

        return context
```

This is the Error Message i get

> ValueError at /data/search/
>
> The view farmapi.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object.
>   It returned None instead.

so as far as i understand i should use a **if** statement?

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'farmapi/search.html'
   http_method_names = ['get']

   def get(self, request):
        query = request.GET.get("q")

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if query is not None and query != '':
            context['farmers'] = Farmer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)|Q(last_name__icontains=query))
            context['animals'] = Animal.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
            return context
        if query is None and query != '':
            context['farmers'] = Farmer.objects.all()
            context['animals'] = Animal.objects.all()
            return context
```

Unfortunately this does not work, i received the same error message. i would appreciate it, if someone has a hint or maybe knows some nice django tutorials with the topic "query, request via templates and filters" - i searched for hours, but most stuff was query and python shell related.

> Update

---

**Solution**

So instead of using classed based view i use now a function and it worked.

```
def search(request):

    query = request.GET.get("q")

    if query is not None and query != '': # <----
        farmers = Farmer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)|Q(last_name__icontains=query))
        animals = Animal.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        context = {'animals': animals,
                   'farmers': farmers}
        return render(request, 'farmapi/search.html', context)
    else:  # <----
        farmers = Farmer.objects.order_by("-id")[0:2]
        animals = Animal.objects.order_by("-id")[0:2]
        context = {'animals': animals,
                   'farmers': farmers}
        return render(request, 'farmapi/search.html', context)
```

however i wished there was a class based way.

Comment: But that can't work at all. Your `get` method does *nothing* apart from defining a variable. Why are you defining that method at all? All the work should go into `get_context_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using classed based view i use now a function and it worked.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")

    if query is not None and query != '': # <----
        farmers = Farmer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)|Q(last_name__icontains=query))
        animals = Animal.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
        context = {'animals': animals,
                   'farmers': farmers}
        return render(request, 'farmapi/search.html', context)
    else:  # <----
        farmers = Farmer.objects.order_by("-id")[0:2]
        animals = Animal.objects.order_by("-id")[0:2]
        context = {'animals': animals,
                   'farmers': farmers}
        return render(request, 'farmapi/search.html', context)
```

however i wished there was a class based way.

p.s i posted this so i can later close this Thread or is there a way to close my own question if i answered it?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following adjustment

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if query is not None and query != '': # <----
            context['farmers'] = Farmer.objects.filter(Q(first_name__icontains=query)|Q(last_name__icontains=query))
            context['animals'] = Animal.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
            return context
        else:  # <----
            context['farmers'] = Farmer.objects.all()
            context['animals'] = Animal.objects.all()
            return context
```

Your conditions for the `if` and `else` statements are a bit confusing, so I suspect that for some inputs neither condition triggered and `None` was therefore returned.

Comment: Yeah right :-) a bit confusing. I tried your approach. But still i get: **The view farmapi.views.HomeView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**